# Compile JNI code with Maven (Final result is a JAR and a DLL)

Tags: maven, java-native-interface

I have a Java project along with some native code that is called via JNI. Before I started integrating my project with Maven it worked perfectly fine through Eclipse,  the native code was compiled to a dll and the program ran fine. Now that I am integrating Maven I'm wondering if anyones had any success in this department?

I've found countless posts about native integration with Maven while googling (many on this site) but none of them seem helpful to me because I need to compile a JAR from one source folder and a DLL from the other while all of the posts I've seen seem to completely rewrite the POM and use third-party libraries to compile native code but completely eliminate the Java aspect.

I've found [this](https://www.mojohaus.org/maven-native/native-maven-plugin/) library that would allow Maven to compile native code but it's 'usage' section isn't very user friendly for someone just starting with maven.

My project layout:

[image]

My autogenerated POM is as follows:

```
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Adventum</groupId>
  <artifactId>Adventum</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Adventum</name>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Should I add an additional `<build> ... </build>` section to the POM and configure the native side there? Even googling I found that to be frowned upon. I found information on [aggregation](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Aggregation) while googling but it isn't clear where I should be putting each individual POM and how I should be linking them.

Rather than ask someone to waste their time thinking of a solution for me, I'm hoping that some users have already found a solution to this? (Incorporating JNI into a Maven project can't be that unheard off...)

Comment: Better take a look into nar-maven-plugin (just search via search engines)...

Comment: @khmarbaise Thank you!